# I want to insert the substrings into an array,But the first one only is added.. How to correct that?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Input: 3 Books

Substrings should be: Boo, ook, oks

I want to add them in the substring array but only "Boo" is added..

Also how can I cout the most repeated string in that array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n;
    int sub_index=0;
    string input;
    string substrings [1000];

    while ( cin >> n >> input != NULL ) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<= input.size()-n ; i++)
        {
            string sub = input.substr(i,n);
            substrings [sub_index]= sub;
            sub_index += n+1;
        }

        //cout the most repeated in substrings array
    }
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a debugging print in your loop, you can see the problem immediately. This change:

```
            string sub = input.substr(i,n);
            std::cout << "storing \"" << sub << "\" at index "
                      << sub_index << std::endl;
            substrings [sub_index]= sub;
            sub_index += n+1;
```

generates this output:

```
storing "Boo" at index 0
storing "ook" at index 4
storing "oks" at index 8
```

I'm not sure why you're incrementing your index the way you are, but that's likely the problem you're hitting.

To determine the most repeated string, you'll need to store both the substring and a count. I suggest you look into using a `std::map` with the string as a key and the count as a value, and once you have all your input, iterate through the map to find the key/value pair with the highest count.